# Get revenue per period for the given dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate revenue by period based on contract start and end dates. I believe creating dynamic columns will increase the code. I am fine even if I get logic to calculate for static columns. I want to produce the data like below.

[image]

I have total revenue to recognize, start and end dates but need to build a waterfall to recognize revenue as per number of days in each period. I am OK to use static columns as well but I am not getting how to calculate revenue for each period.

Comment: What data are you starting with?  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would be very helpful.

Comment: please avoid posting image. It is too small and not readable

Comment: I am starting with sales order data and trying to recognize revenue as per the contract start and end dates and number of days in that period